# How to redirect to a file if exists in .htacess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have an ecommerce website with a few thousand products. About 90% of them have `.webp` images, the other have .jpg. I want to show the `.webp` files if it exists, and if not, to show the .jpg file.

I have written this for wordpress localhost

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).(jpg)$ https://localhost/$1.webp [R=301,L]
```

But it only replaces jpg with webp, which returns error when it doesn't find the .webp files.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.webp/?$ $1.jpg [NC,L]
```

---

---

OR you could following also. Please make sure you use either above OR below following set of Rules one at a time only.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.webp !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.webp/?$ $1.jpg [NC,L]
```